# eclipse mars c/c++ won't build on Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows, gcc

i'm using Eclipse Mars for C/C++ on Windows 7 64-bit

I've tried installing Eclipse from the .zip and the installer.

The first time I did this process, I installed the same verison of Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and installed Eclox from this tutorial: http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/06/25/5-best-eclipse-plugins-1-eclox-with-doxygen-graphviz-and-mscgen/
It all worked fine.

On Windows 7, I did the same thing and I'm getting several errors. Here's the code snippet I'm trying to build:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following problems:

1. /usr/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
2. make: *** [helloworld.o] Error 127
3. Program "g++" not found in PATH
4. Program "gcc" not found in PATH

[image: Eclipse Problems]

Comment: You have the IDE. Did you install a compiler? If not, I recommend a quick google for mingw.

Answer (score 1):

This was the way I found that worked.

Install MinGW [Installing MinGW](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html#mingw)

In Eclipse:

1. Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> New C/C++ Project Wizard -> Makefile Project -> Binary Parsers. Check "PE Windows Parser" and move it up
2. Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment. Select. "Path"

Right click on your project in the project explorer

1. Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Binary Parsers
2. Select “PE Windows Parser” and move it up to the top